# How to add selection box dynamically in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

Here is a partial form _standards.html.erb we want to add to the view dynamically:

```
  <p><%= f.association :standards, :collection => Standard.active_std.all(:order => 'name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id :include_blank => true %></p>
```

Here is the view form itself _form_new.html.erb which calls _standards.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @rfq do |f| %>    

  <div id="std">
  <%= render :partial => 'standards/standards', :collection => @rfq.standards, :locals => { :f => f } %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_function("Add std", nil) do |page| %> 
    page.insert_html :bottom, 'std', :partial => 'standards/standards', :object => @rfq.standards.build 
  <% end %> 

  <%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>  
<% end %>
```

This solution did not work as link_to_function was not reacting to click by loading the _standards.html.erb. This solution seems out of date and does not work in rails 3.1.0. I am wondering if there is other solution to add dynamic content to the view page in rails 3.1.0. If you do, please don't hesitate to post. Thanks.

Comment: Dynamically meaning without refreshing the page?

Comment: I mean adding content by request, such as clicking add button to add a selection box by loading _standards.html.erb.

Comment: AJAX requests for dynamically updating the page are done a bit different in Rails 3.  You should watch this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: railscasts#205 only talked about unobtrusive js and did not provide a solution to the question here.

Comment: What I was saying is that unobtrusive javascript is *the* way that Rails 3 uses for dynamically updating a page.  You would do `render.js` in the controller action and then update the page via the javascript callback on the page.  Here's a good tutorial to start you off: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Comment: There is subtle difference between the question here and that in tutorial. The example in tutorial uses link_to. The question here needs to use link_to_function. I haven't found a good example for link_to_function for rails 3.1.0 or above.

Comment: That's because no one uses inline javascript in `link_to` functions anymore... Again, they use unobtrusive javascript which is what that example was showing.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is coming months after you need it but hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles across this question.  Here is how you can dynamically add a selection box unobtrusively for your example.

_form_new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @rfq do |f| %> 

  <a id="add-selection-box" href="#">Add Selection Box</a>
  <div id="std"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add-selection-box").click(function() {  
        $("#std").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'standards/standards', :collection => @rfq.standards, :locals => { :f => f })) %>");
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Here is how you can do it using link_to_function

_form_new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @rfq do |f| %>
  <%= add_selection_box "Add Selection Box", @rfq.standards, f %>
  <div id="std"></div>
<% end %>
```

helpers/my_form_helper.rb

```
module MyFormHelper
  def add_selection_box(name, collection, form)
    page = %{
      partial = "#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "standards/standards", :collection => collection, :locals => { :f => form }))}";

      $("#std").append(partial);
    }

    link_to_function name, page
  end
end
```